# jQuery Get Modal Window working right

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to get each time you press the arrow, it moves it one more , but currently its only showing the content for:

```
<div id="dialog" class="window">
One
<a href="#"class="close"/>Close it</a>
</div>
```

When I click it, it only shows that dialog window dispite having these below it:

```
 <div id="dialog22" class="window">
Two 
<a href="#"class="close"/>Close it</a>
</div>
<div id="dialog3" class="window">
Three 
<a href="#"class="close"/>Close it</a>
</div>
<div id="dialog4" class="window">
Four 
<a href="#"class="close"/>Close it</a>
</div>
```

**FULL CODE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Simple JQuery Modal Window from Queness</title>
<!-- TUTORIAL:::::::: http://sixrevisions.com/tutorials/javascript_tutorial/create-a-slick-and-accessible-slideshow-using-jquery/-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
/** 
 * Slideshow style rules.
 */
#slideshow {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:640px;
    height:263px;
    //background:transparent url(img/bg_slideshow.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
    background-color:#999;
    position:relative;
}
#slideshow #slidesContainer {
  margin:0 auto;
  width:560px;
  height:263px;
  overflow:auto; /* allow scrollbar */
  position:relative;
}
#slideshow #slidesContainer .slide {
  margin:0 auto;
  width:540px; /* reduce by 20 pixels of #slidesContainer to avoid horizontal scroll */
  height:263px;
}

/** 
 * Slideshow controls style rules.
 */
.control {
  display:block;
  width:39px;
  height:263px;
  text-indent:-10000px;
  position:absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#leftControl {
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background:transparent url(img/control_left.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
}
#rightControl {
  top:0;
  right:0;
  background:transparent url(img/control_right.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
}

/** 
 * Style rules for Demo page
 */
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  font:normal 11px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color:#ccc;
}
a {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration:underline;
}
body {
  // background:#393737 url(img/bg_body.jpg) repeat-x top left;
  background-color:#fff;
}
#pageContainer {
  margin:0 auto;
  width:960px;
}
#pageContainer h1 {
  display:block;
  width:960px;
  height:114px;
  // background:transparent url(img/bg_pagecontainer_h1.jpg) no-repeat top left;
  //background-color:#666;
  font-size:4em;
  color:red;
  text-indent: -10000px;
}
.slide h2, .slide p {
  margin:15px;
}
.slide h2 {
  font:italic 24px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  color:#ccc;
  letter-spacing:-1px;
}
.slide img {
  float:right;
  margin:0 15px;
}
#footer {
  height:100px;
}
#footer p {
  margin:30px auto 0 auto;
  display:block;
  width:560px;
  height:40px;
}
-->
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  var currentPosition = 0;
  var slideWidth = 560;
  var slides = $('.slide');
  var numberOfSlides = slides.length;

  // Remove scrollbar in JS
  $('#slidesContainer').css('overflow', 'hidden');

  // Wrap all .slides with #slideInner div
  slides
    .wrapAll('<div id="slideInner"></div>')
    // Float left to display horizontally, readjust .slides width
    .css({
      'float' : 'left',
      'width' : slideWidth
    });

  // Set #slideInner width equal to total width of all slides
  $('#slideInner').css('width', slideWidth * numberOfSlides);

  // Insert controls in the DOM
  $('#slideshow')
    .prepend('<span class="control" id="leftControl">Clicking moves left</span>')
    .append('<span class="control" id="rightControl">Clicking moves right</span>');

  // Hide left arrow control on first load
  manageControls(currentPosition);

  // Create event listeners for .controls clicks
  $('.control')
    .bind('click', function(){
    // Determine new position
    currentPosition = ($(this).attr('id')=='rightControl') ? currentPosition+1 : currentPosition-1;

    // Hide / show controls
    manageControls(currentPosition);
    // Move slideInner using margin-left
    $('#slideInner').animate({
      'marginLeft' : slideWidth*(-currentPosition)
    });
  });

  // manageControls: Hides and Shows controls depending on currentPosition
  function manageControls(position){
    // Hide left arrow if position is first slide
    if(position==0){ $('#leftControl').hide() } else{ $('#leftControl').show() }
    // Hide right arrow if position is last slide
    if(position==numberOfSlides-1){ $('#rightControl').hide() } else{ $('#rightControl').show() }
  } 
});
</script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {  

    //select all the a tag with name equal to modal
    $('#slidesContainer li a[name=modal]').click(function(e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        //Get the A tag
        var id = $(this).attr('href');

        //Get the screen height and width
        var maskHeight = $(document).height();
        var maskWidth = $(window).width();

        //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
        $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

        //transition effect     
        $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);    
        $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);  

        //Get the window height and width
        var winH = $(window).height();
        var winW = $(window).width();

        //Set the popup window to center
        $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
        $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

        //transition effect
        $(id).fadeIn(2000); 

    });

    //if close button is clicked
    $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#mask').hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });     

    //if mask is clicked
    $('#mask').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });         

});

</script>
<style>
body {
font-family:verdana;
font-size:15px;
}

a {color:#333; text-decoration:none}
a:hover {color:#ccc; text-decoration:none}

#mask {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  z-index:9000;
  background-color:#000;
  display:none;
}

#boxes .window {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:440px;
  height:200px;
  display:none;
  z-index:9999;
  padding:20px;
}
#boxes .window001 {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:440px;
  height:200px;
  display:none;
  z-index:9999;
  padding:20px;
}
#boxes .window002 {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:440px;
  height:200px;
  display:none;
  z-index:9999;
  padding:20px;
}
#boxes .window003 {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:440px;
  height:200px;
  display:none;
  z-index:9999;
  padding:20px;
}
#boxes .window004 {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:440px;
  height:200px;
  display:none;
  z-index:9999;
  padding:20px;
}

#boxes #dialog, #boxes #dialog22, #boxes #dialog3, #boxes #dialog4 {
  width:375px; 
  height:203px;
  padding:10px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
}

#boxes #dialog1 {
  width:375px; 
  height:203px;
}

#dialog1 .d-header {
  background:url(images/login-header.png) no-repeat 0 0 transparent; 
  width:375px; 
  height:150px;
}

#dialog1 .d-header input {
  position:relative;
  top:60px;
  left:100px;
  border:3px solid #cccccc;
  height:22px;
  width:200px;
  font-size:15px;
  padding:5px;
  margin-top:4px;
}

#dialog1 .d-blank {
  float:left;
  background:url(images/login-blank.png) no-repeat 0 0 transparent; 
  width:267px; 
  height:53px;
}

#dialog1 .d-login {
  float:left;
  width:108px; 
  height:53px;
}

#boxes #dialog2 {
  background:url(images/notice.png) no-repeat 0 0 transparent; 
  width:326px; 
  height:229px;
  padding:50px 0 20px 25px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<div id="pageContainer">
<!-- Slideshow HTML -->
<div id="slideshow">
  <div id="slidesContainer">
        <li><a href="#dialog" name="modal">
        <div class="slide">
          Content 1
        </div>
        </a></li>
        <li><a href="#dialog22" name="modal">
        <div class="slide">
          Content 2
        </div>
        </a></li>
        <li><a href="#dialog3" name="modal">
        <div class="slide">
          Content 3
        </div>
        </a></li>
        <li><a href="#dialog4" name="modal">
        <div class="slide">
          Content 4
        </div>
        </a></li>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Slideshow HTML -->
</div>
</ul>

<div style="font-size:10px;color:#ccc">Except where otherwise noted, content on this site is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 License.</div>

<div id="boxes">

<!--contents-->
<div id="dialog" class="window">
One
<a href="#"class="close"/>Close it</a>
</div>
 <div id="dialog22" class="window">
Two 
<a href="#"class="close"/>Close it</a>
</div>
<div id="dialog3" class="window">
Three 
<a href="#"class="close"/>Close it</a>
</div>
<div id="dialog4" class="window">
Four 
<a href="#"class="close"/>Close it</a>
</div> 
<!-- Start of Login Dialog -->  
<div id="dialog1" class="window">
  <div class="d-header">
    <input type="text" value="username" onclick="this.value=''"/><br/>
    <input type="password" value="Password" onclick="this.value=''"/>    
  </div>
  <div class="d-blank"></div>
  <div class="d-login"><input type="image" alt="Login" title="Login" src="images/login-button.png"/></div>
</div>
<!-- End of Login Dialog -->  



<!-- Start of Sticky Note -->
<div id="dialog2" class="window">
  So, with this <b>Simple Jquery Modal Window</b>, it can be in any shapes you want! Simple and Easy to modify : ) <br/><br/>
<input type="button" value="Close it" class="close"/>
</div>
<!-- End of Sticky Note -->



<!-- Mask to cover the whole screen -->
  <div id="mask"></div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Anyone see why this isn't working? Its driving me insane lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give each of your new modal windows a higher z-index in the css.
Therefore when dialog 2 is created it will sit on top of dialog 1 due to its higher z index.

you could do this in your js file on creation of the window, just make sure your newly created dialog has a higher z index than the last.